# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run a tensorflow code in v2.0 and I'mg getting the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'
```

I don't want to simply remove it from the code.

- why this code has been removed?
- why should I do instead?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

tf.logging was for `Logging and Summary Operations` and in TF 2.0 it has been removed in favor of the open-source absl-py, and to make the main tf.* namespace has functions that will be used more often.

In TF.2 lesser used functions are gone or moved into sub-packages like tf.math

So instead of tf.logging you could:

- `tf_upgrade_v2` will upgrade script and changes `tf.logging` to `tf.compat.v1.logging`
- Python logging module can be used instead
- Import absl-py library

Comment: NOTE: This fix does not work for `bert-as-a-service`.

Comment: useing tensorflow-v2.5, thanks for your guide!

Comment: Syntax is as follows:  **tf_upgrade_v2 --infile foo.py --outfile bar.py** ,
  **tf_upgrade_v2 --infile foo.ipynb --outfile bar.ipynb** ,
  **tf_upgrade_v2 --intree ~/code/old --outtree ~/code/new** ,
Note : replace foo.py with your filename

Comment: Any chance of an alternative as simple as tf.logging.info("...") ?
tf.print() ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using someone else's code it's better to install **same Tensorflow version as the author used**, or downgrade your Tensorflow version. You may wanna try this:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

Or if you have gpu:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

You may still get **depricated** warnings, however you don't need to modify several files replacing `tf` with `tf.compat.v1`